# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 directions capabilities

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, directions

I use Google Maps js API v3. I can show directions with waypoints based on [this](http://code.google.com/intl/hu/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints). What I want is getting the points of the direction. Lets say the direction line goes from Budapest to Warsaw. I want to get all latitude and longitude on that line. But I don't find any build in function or workaround for this. I don't copy [code](http://code.google.com/intl/hu/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#InspectingResults) here as the [tutorial works for me](http://code.google.com/intl/hu/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex.html), I can start from that.
(Of course it isn't a good idea to make lot of waypoints.)

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595829/google-maps-api-get-points-along-route-between-lat-long). It isn't solution for my problem, as its not for API3

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Based on Matty F's answer I found out I searched for the result object's routs array's overview_path field. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calling the `DirectionsService.route` method, pass a callback as the second parameter. The first parameter in the callback will be a `DirectionsResult` object. Get all the points of the directions by looping through the children of this object:

```
DirectionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    var pointsArray = [];

    for (var route in result.routes) {
        for (var leg in route.legs) {
            for (var step in leg.steps) {
                for (var latlng in step.path) {
                    pointsArray.push(latlng)
                }
            }
        {
    }
});
```

In the end, pointsArray will hold all the LatLng points between the start and destination points.