# How to get the list of waypoints of a route displayed on the Google maps, through their API V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The **GDirections** class of Google maps API helped me in "displaying" the route between two supplied coordinates.

Now I want a list of **ALL** the coordinates on that route.

Any hints on how to get this?

**EDIT**
Just now discovered http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRoute

Its **overview_path** property gives the list of ALL the waypoints of the route.
Is **DirectionsRoute**the right class for this problem Or I am missing some point?

**EDIT - 2**

With the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960296/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-directions-capabilities/5960722#5960722) shown by **mkram0** below, I have modified the code as follows:

The Map IS getting displayed.
The Route IS getting displayed.

I was thinking of placing markers on the first four coordinates on the route. Those markers don't get displayed. Any helps? Please.

```
directionsService.route (request, 
                            function (result, status) 
                            {
                                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                                {
                                    directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);

                                    for (var route in result.routes) 
                                    {
                                        for (var leg in route.legs) 
                                        {
                                            for (var step in leg.steps) 
                                            {
                                                for (var latlng in step.path) 
                                                {
                                                    pointsArray.push(latlng);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[0],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });

                                    var point2 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[1],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });

                                    var point3 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[2],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });

                                    var point4 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[3],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Can you show the code you already have so we have a starting point?

Comment: I didn't put any code deliberately. REASON: My code contains the way for displaying the markers and the route between them, only. I haven't written the code for displaying ALL the "waypoints/coordinates" on that route because I don't know which API(default method) is responsible for that. And secondly I don't expect anyone to write code for me, I just wanted to know whether an API responsible for this exists or not? Or there is some know algorithm to be implemented for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this myself :)
The **overview_path** was the correct method w.r.t displaying the coordinates:
Just for checking if this really shows something, I have displayed markers on the resulting first four coordinates.

```
directionsService.route (request, 
                            function (result, status) 
                            {
                                alert(status);
                                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                                {
                                    directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);

                                    var pointsArray = [];

                                    pointsArray = result.routes[0].overview_path;

                                    var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[0],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });

                                    var point2 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[1],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });

                                    var point3 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[2],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });

                                    var point4 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[3],
                                        draggable:true,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });
```

Answer (score 3):

The overview_path doc says it returns

> An array of LatLngs representing the
>   entire course of this route. The path
>   is simplified in order to make it
>   suitable in contexts where a small
>   number of vertices is required.

I don't interpret that to mean the same thing as returning an array of all the waypoints on a route. And in your question, it's not clear to me whether you want waypoints or coordinates (lat long) or both. If I were you, I'd also consider `legs`, which returns

> an array of DirectionsLegs, each of
>   which contains information about the
>   steps of which it is composed. There
>   will be one leg for each waypoint or
>   destination specified.

Within `DirectionsLeg`, I think you should also take a look at `steps` and `via_waypoints`.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

or [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 directions capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960296/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-directions-capabilities)